# Android studio check for compatibility with API < 19

Tags: android, android-studio

I have an application project with this settings:

```
android {
  compileSdkVersion 21
  buildToolsVersion '19.1.0'

  defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 10
    targetSdkVersion 19
  }
  buildTypes {
    release {

    }
  }
  compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
  }
}
```

And I have a block with try-with resources which not use checking if Build.SDK is less than API 19.
I don't get any errors from IDE about it.
I ran a program on emulator with target SDK Android 4.1.2 and everything is fine, also checked on the device with Android 4.2.2. The program is invoke this code, checked with the debugger.
Is everything ok? I expect that there is might be compatibility errors from IDE but there's not.

If I try to create a new project in IDE with same minVersionSdk 10, I've got a error from IDE about the compatibility.
But in my working project I don't get it.
I don't know, is there any other settings for compatibility, not in build.gradle and AndroidManifest.xml? Why is it working on API < 19 ?

**UPDATE:
you need to check Lint settings in Android Studio.
Editor - Inspections
Android Lint, Calling new methods on older versions**

Comment: "I've got a error from IDE about the compatibility" What is the error?

Comment: And why don't you fire it up on an API10 emulator?

Comment: The error, that try-with-resources construction is uncompatible with API < 19. Why API 10 emulator, what's the difference with API14 emulator about my problem??

Comment: You gave it a go on API 14? Because you only mention API 16 and from what I've read it actually works mostly from API 15 plus.

Comment: You mean that this actually works on API 15 and futher, but officially is working on API 19?

Comment: I've put more detail in an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is it working on API < 19 ?

According to this: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=73483 It "mostly works" from API 15, and you tested on an API 16 emulator (4.1.2).

Issue raiser states:

> Since it was unhidden in API level 19, try-with-resources is backwards compatible down to API level 15.

Google member replies (edited down):

> `AutoCloseable` was in ics. and it's just an interface; it's javac that emits code to actually do the closing. iirc there are fewer classes that are `AutoCloseable` in ics than we actually unhid
>
> so "backwards compatible" is a bit misleading. "mostly works" is closer to the truth.

Because it's not fully compatible, the warning is from API 19.

As to why you are not seeing the warning, I think that is down to your very old `buildToolsVersion` which dates back to December 2013. https://developer.android.com/tools/revisions/build-tools.html

> You should always keep your Build Tools component updated by downloading the latest version using the Android SDK Manager

Comment: Thanks about the explanation, why is it working. I made a mistake because test only with API 16. I still don't undestand why is the IDE don't show me compatibility problems.

Comment: Well your `buildToolsVersion` is very low/old (Dec 2013). I think that could affect the lint messages. Try with the same version the new project uses.

Comment: And/or try `21.1.2` as that matches your `compileSdkVersion`. https://developer.android.com/tools/revisions/build-tools.html

Comment: Weston, thank you for your help! I updated buildToolVersion. Also, as I think there was disabled Lint setting about my problem. I updated an IDE to the last version and didn't import the settings from previous version. Now I have checked lint "Android - Calling new methods on older versions".

Answer (score 1):

If you only use methods which were created before API 10 (You can check [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/packages.html)) everything is ok.

If you are not sure, you can run lint (by right clicking on your root folder) and then you can check if lint warn you about deprecated method usage.

If you want more explanation don't hesitate to comment

Comment: Hello! I ran Analyze - Inspect Code on the whole project by didn't get any error about incompatibility. I added to the end of description that I tried to create a new project and there's compatibility errors with try-with-resources constructions. Can't understand why in my working project there's no checking.